# AddFilter option_active_plugins is executed 6 times. Why?

Tags: plugins, hooks

I've put an adsense script in the `mu-plugins` folder, hooked it to the `option_active_plugins` but it happens to be executed 6 times.

Is it an error?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Maybe post some code, and explain what you're _trying_ to do as opposed to what you've done so far.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic: of course. Just a question.. is it "strange" that this hooks is called more than once?

Comment: No, not at all - this filter will fire anytime `get_option( 'active_plugins' )` is called, which almost certainly happens multiple times per request.

Comment: For me would be enough as an answer. I think it stays very generic and will be useful for many other people. If you put it as an Answer I will accept it.

Comment: I understand that get_option('active_plugins') can be call many time. But in my case it's called 505 times! it seems too many. Or is my project too big?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is it "strange" that this hooks is called more than once?

No, not at all - this filter will fire anytime `get_option( 'active_plugins' )` is called, which almost certainly happens multiple times per request.